# Armazenar retorno Javascript em variável php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Galera estou precisando muito armazenar um retorno Javascript em uma variável php.

no meu arquivo js eu tenho o elemento javascript que me retorna o id da minha categoria como mostrado abaixo:

```
document.getElementById("editcategoria").     value = resposta['dados'].Categoria_Prod_idCategoria;
```

no php eu recupero o value em um input com o id="editcategoria":

```
<input type="text" id="editcategoria"  name="editcategoria">
```

Quando executo no navegador está funcionando perfeitamente, mas para atender a minha necessidade eu preciso que ao ser retornado a informação para o php em vez de ser armazenado em um input, eu possa armazenar em uma variável php por exemplo:

```
<?php $variavelphp = retorno do javascript
      echo $variavelphp;?>
```

Já fiz várias pesquisas a respeito mas sem sucesso, caso precisem de mais informações estou a disposição!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Submetendo o formulário contendo o input com atributo `name="editcategoria"`, o valor do input será recebido pelo PHP como `$_POST['editcategoria']` ou `$_GET['editcategoria']`, dependendo se o método de envio do formulário for `post` ou `get`.

Antes de submeter de volta para o servidor, o php não sabe o que está acontecendo no lado do cliente.